# Is Edmure Tully a knight?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I thought that Edmure Tully wasn't a knight, but on reading [his wiki page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Edmure_Tully) for asoiaf.westeros.org, his title is listed as "Ser" and the page is in the category of "Knights". On Edmure Tully's [page](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Edmure_Tully) on gameofthrones.wikia.com, it says

> Edmure Tully is a middling knight...

And [a Tumblr user](http://blackfishblues.tumblr.com/post/19399073155/re-ser-edmure-tully) mentions that he is a knight.

Yes, these are all unreliable sources, and I admit I struggled to turn up anything more than those three links. And nothing on any of those links has a source confirming that Edmure is a knight. Yet the fact that more than one person believes he is compels me to ask: is there any canon support (or otherwise official confirming material,) for Edmure Tully being a knight? Answers from the show or the books are acceptable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the appendix of *A Storm of Swords* (because that was the one most readily available), the lines of the lesser houses, under House Tully he is listed as

> —SER EDMURE

So he is canonically a knighted knight.

Comment: I checked my appendix for Game of Thrones, he's listed as `SER EDMURE` there, too. Thank you :).

Comment: Of all the places to look, it never occurred to me to look in the appendix. :) Too many years of internet, my brain is completely digitalized.

Comment: I felt exactly the same way when I saw this answer, @TLP :).

Comment: Are there unknighted knights or nonknighted knights?

Comment: @Petersaber I suppose there are people that are kinghtly but not knighted (maybe Brienne) and knights can be stripped of lands and titles as Ned intended for Gregor Clegane

Answer (score 3):

Although the accepted answer is correct that mainly gives us information from an out of universe point of view. From an in universe point of view he is also definitely a Ser:

> Ser Raymun Darry spoke up. "**Ser Edmure** had summoned me to Riverrun with all my strength. I was camped across the river from his walls, awaiting his commands, when the word reached me. By the time I could return to my own lands, Clegane and his vermin were back across the Red Fork, riding for Lannister's hills."
>   
> <sub>A Game of Thrones, Eddard XI</sub>

He is also mentioned again as a Ser by Tywin Lannister when talking about capturing him.

> "Your brother has been covering himself with glory," his father said. "He smashed the Lords Vance and Piper at the Golden Tooth, and met the massed power of the Tullys under the walls of Riverrun. The lords of the Trident have been put to rout. **Ser Edmure Tully was taken captive, with many of his knights and bannermen.** Lord Blackwood led a few survivors back to Riverrun, where Jaime has them under siege. The rest fled to their own strongholds."
>   
> <sub>A Game of Thrones, Tyrion VII</sub>