# Any hints that J might wed D?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The answers in [If J = L + R, why would his claim to the throne come before this Targaryen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65586/if-j-l-r-why-would-his-claim-to-the-throne-come-before-this-targaryen?rq=1) suggests that J could still possibly ascend the throne.

> If J does equal L + R, then Daenerys is Jon's aunt, who also has claim to the throne, and is lacking an incestuous partner - something she clearly expected and perhaps wanted from the beginning.

They both have so-called gentle hearts, and the series title could be taken as one hint that a union is possible - though it could show the opposite, a meeting but a battle rather than a feast.

Are there other hints or clues in the books or show that suggest such a union might be a future possibility? Any hints or circumstances that show this is impossible or unlikely?

Comment: I have never seen or read anything that indicated Dany WANTED an incestuous relationship. In fact, it would seem that Viserys held that possibility over her head before his death, and she found the idea rather repugnant.

Comment: @Omegacron It's been awhile since I read the first book, and I recall some jealousy/disappointment/sadness/mixed-feelings on her part when he went out with other women.  Could be that I'm imagining that, though, which is why I wrote "perhaps" in that sentence.

Comment: Fair enough - it's pretty safe to say that, either way, Dany definitely had a love/hate relationship with her brother.

Comment: Isn't J, err, D?

Comment: @TZHX Possibly!

Comment: [*A blue flower growing from a chink in a wall of ice, filling the air with sweetness. . . mother of dragons, bride of fire . . .*](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/Prophecies/Entry/1813)

Comment: @TZHX - There's a big difference between mostly D and all D. Mostly D is slightly A. With all D, well, with all D you're mostly out of luck.

Comment: @Omegacron Ha!  I'm imagining J uttering, as his chest is pressed, "Wiiiiinteeeeeeeer iiiiiis cooooomiiiiiiing...."

Comment: @Omegacron OK. It's several years since aDwD came out so my memory is a little fuzzy. I just had it in my head that he was done -- but we've seen C come back, so I guess anything goes.

Comment: I'm thinking that an ASOIAF alphabet book is needed here.

Comment: @TZHX true, but C was all the way D, yet only mostly came back A. Like 70/30 or something. Maybe 80/20, it's vague. J is only mostly D, so he's probably ok.

Answer (score 3):

The dragon has three heads, and so we need three candidates for dragon riders. And the overall title is *A Song of Ice and Fire*, suggesting one or more unions between Stark and Targaryen, which Mr Martin has been to some pains to point out has never happened in the history of Westeros. My own best guess is that Jon (= L + R, and hence the product of the only Stark/Targaryen union) will end up marrying both his aunt Daenerys and his cousin Arya, thus adding pure-blood Targaryen and pure-blood Stark to the mix, and they will be the three dragon riders. The main hints that this is possible are the frequent incestuous and/or polygamous marriages in the Targaryen family tree.

Comment: Have you read the recently published GRRM letter that initiated the series? He gives a quick overview of the story and may or may not contains spoilers (lots of things were changed in the final product), but it does shine an interesting light on your theory :)

Comment: I've always thought the same, but never included Arya on the equation... but sounds quite well...

Comment: Jon + Dany = slight ew . Jon + Arya = full EW

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> John's apparent/possible death

Bran's vision

> ...his bastard brother Jon sleeping alone in a cold bed, his skin growing pale and hard as the memory of all warmth fled from him...

*May* suggest

> that Jon will recover, perhaps as something slightly different after his death/injury.  Loss of his memory as a warm being may change him in significant ways, though.

Then, poking through Daenery's vision:

> A blue flower grew from a chink in a wall of ice, and filled the air with sweetness.

May suggest

> that Jon, the son of Lyanna (who loved blue roses) will bloom at the wall, and the sweetness filled air suggests that he will become personally (possibly romantically) important or valuable to Daenerys.

That same vision also has:

> A corpse stood at the prow of a ship, eyes bright in his dead face, grey lips smiling sadly.

If Jon

> does die and is brought to life again, (which is the only way he can be released from his covenant to the Night's Watch), this could portend his coming to Daenerys. There are a lot of reasons this could be another person, but keep in mind that Winter is coming, and chances are good the only way Westeros will survive is with the willing aid of the dragons.

And

> I don't know that Daenerys will have any reason to search out Jon, but Jon will certainly have reason to go to Daenerys. However, it's quite possible that he would go seek her help even while under the covenant of the Night's Watch.  He doesn't have to be released from his promise to seek her help.  On the other hand he may not be able to fill the air with "sweetness" for Daenerys if he is still under covenant.  On the Others other hand the book is filled with examples of people with strong convictions which they then broke for what seemed to them worthy reasons, so he may not need to die to be convinced to break his oath.

Other visions, particularly about lightbringer and that Daenerys must touch the light also suggest a meeting of some sort, but are significantly less strong in terms of romantic inclinations towards each other.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting some of those prophecies. All memory of warmth leaving Jon is surely just a metaphor, a way of saying that he'll be cold when serving on the Wall. And the corpse at the prow of a ship is more likely to be Jon Connington or Victarion Greyjoy than Jon Snow, who has never (to date) been on a ship.

Comment: The visions that Bran had were all snapshots of what people were doing at the time. The whole quote is `Finally he [Bran] looked north. He saw the Wall shining like blue crystal, and his bastard brother Jon sleeping alone in a cold bed, his skin growing pale and hard as the memory of all warmth fled from him .` This is before Jon made friends, and he slept apart from the others, so he was alone. It actually also says "bed", which implies he is not dead. Many have over-interpreted this.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

**Spoilers for Season 7 below so be warned.**

---

This is hinted at with the subtleties in the way the two interact with each other throughout the season. However, it is first explicitly spelled out by Tyrion.

> Daenerys Targaryen: I don't want you to be a hero. Heroes do stupid things and they die. Drogo, Jorah, Dario, even this Jon Snow, they all try to outdo each other of who can do the stupidist, bravest thing.
>   Tyrion Lannister: It's interesting these heroes you name. Drogo, Jorah, Dario, even this Jon Snow, they all fell in love with you.
>   Daenerys Targaryen: Jon Snow's not in love with me.
>   Tyrion lannister: Oh, my mistake. I suppose he stares at you longingly because he's hopeful for a successful military alliance.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 6, "Beyond the Wall"</sub>

Later at the end of the same episode Dany visits Jon in his bed after he returns from the North and the two share an interesting interaction where they both seem to be fighting with their emotions vs duties.

Lastly, of course they both give into their emotions in the Season 7 finale #boatsex.