# Has anyone known married for love in Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Do we have knowledge of someone relatively important (not necessarily a faction heir but neither a peasant) that married only for love?

With this I mean that they know each other, a proposal and actually fall in love for each other (awww :D) before getting married. Because we all know how Catelyn came to love Ned, but after marrying him. Before that, Catelyn was supposed to marry Brandon Stark.

I'm particularly interested in the courtship process and the proposal too, I've watched the entire TV series, so just avoid any important spoiler that are in last book but not in TV series (really not care of minor spoilers).

**Edit:** Would be great if a list is made of all the ones who married for love, there shouldn't be a lot.

Comment: Jorah Mormont is the best example for this.

Comment: I think Rob Stark is a better example.

Comment: eh jorah married because HE was in love, his wife, was not in love with him, just in his status as a champion.

Comment: Great, we should make a list of them, probably there are not too much

Comment: @AleOtero93 there are quite a few. It is not that irregular. There are even targaryens that married out of love others than targaryens, i just don't recall the names right.

Comment: speaking of best example - [Duncan Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Duncan_Targaryen), crown prince that gave up the throne for love.

Comment: that's a great example @NikaG.

Comment: One could argue that Rob Stark married for honor, not necessarily love.

Comment: @chepner I agree, he even said: "I couldn't do anything else" after slept with the girl, it was more honor... That leave us only with Duncan Targaryen so far...

Comment: Mance probably counts, but then the free folk play by their own rules. Tywin and Joanna were pretty happy, and I can't see Tywin letting his ineffectual dad tell him who to marry?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I will make a few assumptions here:

1. We're talking about the [Westerosi](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Westeros) only
2. Only nobles, no smallfolk
3. They married *when* they were in love, unlike Ned and Cat who found love *after* they were married
4. The love has to be mutual (sorry Jorah)

---

### Lannister Pride

**[Tywin](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tywin_Lannister) and [Joanna](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Joanna_Lannister)**
It is ironic that the hardest man in Westeros, one who feels nothing is more important than solidifying his family's heritage and rank; marries for love, and his own cousin no less. This is what makes their marriage a loving one, there was no advancement, not pact, no alliance to be made; just love.

Tyrion tells us this:

> Lord Tywin seldom spoke of his wife, but Tyrion had heard his uncles talk of the love between them. In those days, his father had been Aerys’s Hand, and many people said that Lord Tywin Lannister ruled the Seven Kingdoms, but Lady Joanna ruled Lord Tywin.
> <sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: Book 3 - A Storm of Swords, Chapter Thrity-Eight ([Tyrion V](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Storm_of_Swords-Chapter_38)).*</sup>

Most say that Tywin lost his smile after Lady Joanna died.

**[Tyrion Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_Lannister) and [Tysha](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tysha)**
Don't make me cry. Leave me I don't want to talk about it.

`Where do whores go?`

### Targaryens aren't loveless

**[Aegon V Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_V_Targaryen) and [Betha Blackwood](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Betha_Blackwood)**
Our old mate **Egg**, lived with the smallfolk, started from the bottom and fell in love. It should be noted that he was able to do this mostly because he was so far down the line of succession that it wasn't politically damaging for him to do so. However, him and Betha loved each other.

This is funny because due to their actions their children (as pointed out below) also married for love following Aegon and Betha's example.

**Prince [Duncan Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Duncan_Targaryen) and [Jenny of Oldstones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jenny_of_Oldstones)**
They eloped. Prince Duncan - also known as Duncan The Small and Prince of Dragonflies - was the first son of the King, King [Aegon V Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_V_Targaryen) (Egg) and was betrothed to a daughter of Lord [Lyonel Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyonel_Baratheon) (The Laughing Storm), but Prince Duncan broke the betrothal and eloped with Jenny of Oldstones, giving up his right as heir to The Throne.

**Prince [Jaehaerys II Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_II_Targaryen) and Princess [Shaera Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shaera_Targaryen)**
Prince Duncan's second brother and Aerys "The Mad King"'s father. He too was betrothed (to [Celia Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Celia_Tully)) but he loved his sister Princess Shaera Targaryen, Aegon's eldest daughter (who was also betrothed - to [Luthor Tyrell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Luthor_Tyrell)). They decided to follow in Duncan's footsteps and eloped and got married.

It was said of them:

> from a young age, Jaehaerys had been of a more traditional frame of mind, as he was in love with his sister, Princess Shaera. Shaera, in turn, desired him. King Aegon V and Queen Betha observed this and were alerted because of it. They did everything they could to separate the two siblings, yet this only served to inflame their passion
> <sup>*-http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_II_Targaryen#cite_note-Rtwoiaf_aegon_v.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-7.*</sup>

**[Aegon I Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen) and [Visenya Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Visenya_Targaryen) and [Rhaenys Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenys_Targaryen)**
Yes, [he married *both* of his sisters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen#Early_life), his older sister Visenya and his younger sister Rhaenys, and they both loved him very much as he did them.

They didn't call him "Aegon The Conqueror" for nothing... (sorry).

Spoilers re Rhaegar:

> **Prince [Rhaegar Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegar_Targaryen) and Lady [Lyanna Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyanna_Stark)**
>  Although it is not confirmed, many believe that Rhaegar and Lyanna [actually got married](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65589/21267). There is a fair amount of evidence supporting this. If it is true, then it would mean that they were married for love.

### Other

**Prince [Doran Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Doran_Martell) and Lady [Mellario of Norvos](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mellario)**
It's true, they're estranged now, but they were married for love (or at least *they* thought it was love). You see, they were attracted to each other, they had found something they thought was love; which we now know as infatuation.

The author, George R. R. Martin [says this](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Asshai.com_Interview_in_Barcelona) of their marriage:

> It wasn't a good marriage. They married because of an attraction to something new and exotic. Sometimes, attraction happens when you least expect it. He was a prince of a distant country, and she was a woman full of life, who was very appealing, who came from a very different culture. When she comes to Dorne, she finds that there are customs that are different from those of Norvos, especially regarding the fostering away of children to others. This wasn't a political marriage, nor a magical one, it was simply an example of human nature. Sometimes relationships start on a good foot: you become acquainted, there's a great sexual attraction, you establish a relationship, you marry... and then in four or five years you realize that you don't really have anything in common, that at best you've made a mistake and are in a situation that doesn't have any easy solution in a society such as that of the Seven Kingdoms, where divorce simply isn't common. This is an example that it's not only marriages of convenience that fail, but even the marriages for love can fail.
>   Sometimes the marriages of convenience in the Seven Kingdoms come out well and those that are for love don't...
> <sup>*-http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Asshai.com_Interview_in_Barcelona*</sup>

**[Davos Seaworth](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Davos_Seaworth) and [Marya Seaworth](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Marya_Seaworth)**
This is a bit "iffy". For one, they weren't nobles at the time they got married (he was a smuggler and she was the daughter of a carpenter). There's also no hard evidence that they love each other, but they do seem happy.

**[Edmure Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Edmure_Tully) and [Roslin Frey](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Roslin_Frey)**
Another "iffy" one. They do definitely care for each other, and I'd dare say Edmure was smitten as soon as he saw her. She also seemed to grow fond of him, even during [the wedding](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Wedding). She's is most definitely sad about the turn of events and wants to have her Edmure back.

**[Robb Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robb_Stark) and [Jeyne Westerling](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jeyne_Westerling)**
Another "iffy" one. I will include this one because it's entirely possible that even though Robb married Jeyne so as to preserve her "honour"; they could easily have loved each other anyway. They certainly seem to be at least caring, if not loving of each other *after* marriage, and they hadn't been married that long.

Comment: How about Tyrion and Tysha? He loved her, she seemed to be genuinely fond of him after comforting her when she was chased, there might have been an element of gold-digging / status-chasing but didn't they live in a commoner's cottage until Jaime told on him?

Comment: I'm also tempted to suggest Marge and Renly, their marriage allowed people in love to be together (just wasn't each other...)

Comment: @user568459 Weird, I thought I had written Tyrion and Tysha. Also I'm about to do a write up of how GRRM's most loving couples aren't married; Loras and Renly being one :)

Comment: How about Jorah Mormount? Married his last wife out of love, after winning a tournament for her favor.

Comment: @TenthJustice I've discounted Jorah since Lady [Lynesse](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lynesse_Hightower) didn't actually seem to love him for him, she seemed more like a [Gold Digger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gold_digger).

Comment: Would you consider Rhaenyra Targaryen and Daemon Targaryen to be a couple who married for love tho? (Their marriage is another likely candidate tho it appears that Rhaenyra may have been in love with her uncle but Daemon most likely just wanted to get in an important position)

Comment: Also regarding Aegon and Visenya, Aegon's marriage to Visenya was a forced by custom. Aegon's marriage to Rhaenys was however based on love. Which is further reinforced that relation between Visenya and Aegon was dutiful but never warm while Rhaenys was cherished by Aegon. Aegon even actively handed out duties to Visenya to get rid of her for a while

Comment: Also, Jaehaerys I and Alysanne should be there :P  At least in the iffy cases as we do not know if they loved each other before their marriage.

Comment: RE the spoiler this has been confirmed in the show

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't care, because [`only the books are canon`](https://grrm.livejournal.com/490253.html?thread=24647437#t24647437). ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Possible spoiler warning for the HBO TV show (even if you've read all the books):

[Rob Stark and Talissa Maegyr](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Robb_and_Talisa_Stark) marry for love. While Robb had promised Walder Frey to marry one of the Freys, he defies the Freys by instead marrying Talissa, whom he fell in love with while she nursed him after his being injured in battle.  Of course, like how you would expect for *Game of Thrones*, this marriage for love does not last long.

Comment: +1 This answer is perfect for the TV series, in the books is a bit different.

Comment: @AleOtero93 Ironically, I've never watched the show beyond first season. From what I've read, it sounds like the show is less ambiguous, but I still read the book to be, for the most part, a love match.

Comment: What I remember from that scene (I'm from Argentina, so I'm reading the spanish (latin) version) is that after she nursed him, one night they slept and then Rob said something like "What else could I do after that?".

Comment: Yes, that is where it is more open to interpretation.  My personal interpretation is that Rob, being young, believed himself in love and slept with her, with the thought that he would marry her to be honorable also.  Being a Stark, I don't believe he would have done so if he hadn't convinced himself he was in love and wanted to marry her.  It's hard to know 100 percent though, as it happens "off screen," in the books.

Comment: “Being a Stark, I don't believe he would have done so if he hadn't convinced himself he was in love and wanted to marry her.” — Doesn’t that rather contradict the existence of Jon Snow?

Comment: No. The prevailing fan theory, that I'm pretty certain is correct, is that Ned lied about Jon Snow being his bastard.  I'll not say more, because it's spoilerish, beyond that it's against Ned's character, and he's really squirrely about discussing Jon Snow's birth.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here - isn't it pretty much confirmed that Robb's marriage in the books was due to a scheme hatched by Jayne Westerling's mother to get the family back in Tywin's good books after they surrendered so readily? Jayne was pressured into taking advantage of Robb's vulnerability on hearing his bros were dead, then the Westerlings pushed them into a "shotgun wedding". In the TV show it's a textbook doomed marriage for love, but it's very different in the books.

Comment: I always had the impression, that Jayne really loved Rob and didn't know about her mothers and Tywins scheme.